# Django Pagination not working and showing all items in every page

Tags: django

I want to display only one item per page but it's displaying all items in every page and just increasing only page numbers after added new item. see the picture:
[image]

here is my **views.py**

```
def ShowAuthorNOtifications(request):
    user = request.user
    notifications = filters.NotificationFilter(
                      request.GET, 
                      queryset=Notifications.objects.all()
                  ).qs
    paginator = Paginator(notifications, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        response = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        response = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        response = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    
    notification_user =  Notifications.objects.filter(user=user).count()
    Notifications.objects.filter(user=user, is_seen=False).update(is_seen=True)
    template_name ='blog/author_notifications.html'
    
    context = {
        'notifications': notifications,
        
        'notification_user':notification_user,
        'page_obj':response,
    }
    print("##############",context)      
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters
from .models import *
class NotificationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Notifications
        fields = ['notification_type']
```

**models.py:**

```
NOTIFICATION_TYPES = (('New Comment','New Comment'),('Comment Approved','Comment Approved')
notification_type = models.CharField(choices=NOTIFICATION_TYPES,max_length=250,default="New Comment")
```

**html**

```
{% for notification in  notifications  %}
{% if notification.notification_type == "New Comment" %}
  #my code......
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

first I tried to use this  [Function based views pagenations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function) but getting same result. It's just adding page number and showing all items every page.

**#updated question**
as NKSM said I was missing `object_list` in my html template. Now my problems is solved and it's showing only one item per page but how the show page numbers like page1,page2,page3 in pagination section. Now it's showing pagination like this  `Page 1 of 4. next last »`  I want to click page number and it will take me the page.

**#updated2**
I was missing `page_obj` context of my views in my html. After add `page_obj.paginator.page_range` it's working and showing page numbers. Now I can click on page number.

Comment: You should use `object_list` of **Paginator**. See Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#example

Comment: Like: `paginator = Paginator(notifications, 1); cur_page = paginator.page(1); for item in cur_page.object_list`

Comment: NKSM  Thanks for your comment. can you please use my code as example and show me where to apply ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `object_list`([**Django Docs**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.object_list)) of your current page **Paginator**. See  also [**Django Docs example**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#example).

I also suggest you to filter your `notifications` in backend instead to use in template `if notification.notification_type == "New Comment"`

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


def ShowAuthorNOtifications(request):
    user = request.user
    notifications = filters.NotificationFilter(
        request.GET, 
        queryset=Notifications.objects.filter(notification_type="New Comment")
    ).qs
    paginator = Paginator(notifications, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        cur_page = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        cur_page = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        cur_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    
    notification_user =  Notifications.objects.filter(user=user).count()
    Notifications.objects.filter(user=user, is_seen=False).update(is_seen=True)
    
    context = {
        'notification_user': notification_user,
        'cur_page': cur_page,
    }
    print("##############",context)      
    return render(request, 'blog/author_notifications.html', context)
```

template.html:

```
{% for notification in  cur_page.object_list %}
    ...your code...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: NKSM Thanks. It's working now. I was just missing `object_list` in my html template. Thanks for the find out the issue

Comment: NKSM now the only problems is how to show the page numbers? like page1,page2,page3 in pagination section